# PHP split and group array

Tags: php, arrays, key, key-value

I am having a hard time figuring out how to modify my array.  The original array is this...

```
$array = array(
array(
    "fruit" => "pineapple",
    "id" => "aaa",
),
array(
    "fruit" => "orange",
    "id" => "aaa",
),
array(
    "fruit" => "apple",
    "id" => "bbb",
),
array(
    "fruit" => "pear",
    "id" => "bbb",
),
array(
    "fruit" => "peach",
    "id" => "ccc",
),
array(
    "fruit" => "melon",
    "id" => "ccc",
)
);
```

I need to convert this array into an array of keys by id.  For example I would want the end result to look like this...

```
$array = array(
"aaa" => array("pineapple", "orange"),
"bbb" => array("apple", "pear"),
"ccc" => array("peach", "melon"),
);
```

I have attempted to loops through the array and pull out the things I need and rebuild the array but I cant figure it out.  Hopefully someone can help me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by making a new array this way:

```
$array = array(
    array(
        "fruit" => "pineapple",
        "id" => "aaa",
    ),
    array(
        "fruit" => "orange",
        "id" => "aaa",
    ),
    array(
        "fruit" => "apple",
        "id" => "bbb",
    ),
    array(
        "fruit" => "pear",
        "id" => "bbb",
    ),
    array(
        "fruit" => "peach",
        "id" => "ccc",
    ),
    array(
        "fruit" => "melon",
        "id" => "ccc",
    )
);

// empty array
$result = [];

// loop trough data
foreach($array as $value){

    // add item to the $result array. Then make the id the key and the fruit the value
    $result[$value['id']][] = $value['fruit'];

}

//print array
print_r($result);
```

The result will be

```
Array ( [aaa] => Array ( [0] => pineapple [1] => orange ) [bbb] => Array ( [0] => apple [1] => pear ) [ccc] => Array ( [0] => peach [1] => melon ) )
```